# Unable to show RSS in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, rss

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

i am loading webpage using above code. My web page has RSS link. when i click on it, it doesnt show anything. Does it need some setting to show rss in uiwebview?
It works fine on system or safari of device.

Answer (score 1):

UIWebview itself is not able to render RSS feeds !
If you check in Safari, you'll see that Safari is actually loading a special URL to show the RSS feed as html ( http://reader.mac.com/mobile/v1/http%3A%2F%2F...rest of the RSS feed url encoded in the correct format).

What you can do is to detect your RSS feeds in "shouldStartLoadWithRequest" an to open it with http://reader.mac.com/mobile/v1/... !

Comment: Your links are only accessible through iPhones it would seem. Please can you update them to be universal and more descriptive.

Comment: You're right, it's only working for iOS devices ... To be more descriptive, if you want to see this webpage content: http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/Technology , just visit http://reader.mac.com/mobile/v1/http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.nytimes.com%2Fnyt%2Frss%2FTechnology in your UIWebView

Comment: It doesn't work even on uiwebview. Always shows page with message 'This Application Is Viewable Only On iPhone'.